# How to remove the upper and lower checked box out of the render window

Tags: rendering, camera

I'm trying to understand how to remove the upper and lower checked box out of the render window. I tried to adjust several parameters,but I did not succeed...

[image: checked box areas]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The aspect ratio in Render>>Dimensions must be X: 1.000 and Y: 1.000

See the image below.

Good luck.

[image]

Comment: yeah. it works great,but it's interesting to know how it is changed. I didn't change it.

Comment: Yes. If we change the dimensions in the dropdown list we can see the aspect raitos are different. So If we input other dimensions values manually the aspec ratio will not change causing that checked box.